# Determine which molecule has stronger intermolecular force?

Tags: structural-formula, bond, intermolecular-forces

SiH4 and CH4

The only intermolecular force they both have is London Dispersion forces

Strength of LDF is determined by molar mass

molar mass of SiH4 = 32.132

molar mass of CH4 = 48.42

Therefore shouldn't CH4 have a stronger LDF??

The answer says that SiH4 has a greater intermolecular force...why is that?

Comment: Only problem is that you have the wrong molar mass for ch4.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the boiling points.  Interaction is based on geometry (surface area) and polarizability, among other things - and the phase: solid, liquid, vapor.  Molecular weight is not diagnostic.  SiH4 is "fluffy" versus methane being "hard."  Compare the melting and boiling points of decane and isodecane  versus adamantane, all being $\ce{C_{10}}$.  Compare the melting and boiling points of *n*-octane versus 2,2,3,3-tetramethylbutane, both $\ce{C8H_{18}}$.  Complicated.

You might check your MW for methane.  Bells and whistles should have gone off, $\ce{CH4}$ versus $\ce{SiH4}$.

Answer (score 0):

The molar mass of SiH4 is ~32, however the molar mass of CH4 is ~16. This explains the textbook's answer. Uncle Al, however, provides a more detailed answer.